# Hide/show a div after initially loading the DOM?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

I was trying to use a radio button on the screen connected to a property in the ts file that is then hooked into to hide/show another div but it seems that both `*ngIf="isFooSelected"` and `[hidden]="!isFooSelected"` only work on the initial load. Is there another convention for doing this with typescript? Do I needed to do some kind of CSS hack to add and remove a class that sets height to zero?

As requested code. Sorry I assumed it was so simple that it didn't relate to my specific attempt.

.html:

```
    <div class="ui-g-12"><p-radioButton name="group2" value="true" label="Shared" [(ngModel)]="isPouchesShared"></p-radioButton></div>

    <div class="ui-g-12"><p-radioButton name="group2" value="false" label="Individual" [(ngModel)]="isPouchesShared"></p-radioButton></div>

<div [hidden]="!isPouchesShared">
    isPouchesShared == true
</div>

<div *ngIf="isPouchesShared">
    isPouchesShared == true
</div>
```

.ts:

```
export class FooComponent {
    isPouchesShared: boolean = true; }
```

Comment: We can't say why your code doesn't work as expected, and how to fix it, if you don't show your code.

Comment: @JBNizet, Sorry about that, I just assumed it wasn't an error issue but trying to implement with the wrong tools. I've added a bit of my code.

Comment: p-radioButton is not something standard, so it's hard to say what is wrong without guessing. My guess is that it should be `[value]` instead of `value`, as in http://plnkr.co/edit/oO2HfkBNCT639bGNDIZt?p=preview, which works as expected. Otherwise the bound values are the strings 'false' and 'true', which are both truthy.

Comment: @JBNizet, you are right, it's basically copy/pasted from the PrimeNG documentation. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/radiobutton and I do see that the property is changing with each click but am unable to see the div added/removed.

Comment: @JBNizet Just put in regular checkboxes (aka your plunker code) and it works! Thank you! Very stumped now!

Comment: @JBNizet, the [value] binding makes the code work with the PrimeNg component. Thank you! Very green, obviously. :)

Answer (score 0):

Angular setup in the PrimeNg documentation doesn't quite make sense. Works with "[value]".

```
<div class="ui-g-12"><p-radioButton name="group2" value="true" label="Shared" [(ngModel)]="isPouchesShared"></p-radioButton></div>

<div class="ui-g-12"><p-radioButton name="group2" value="false" label="Individual" [(ngModel)]="isPouchesShared"></p-radioButton></div>

<div [hidden]="!isPouchesShared">
  isPouchesShared == true
</div>
```